# Where to put code when monkey patching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monkeypatching

Everything I read about monkey patching says to do something like this:

```
class String
  def foo
    #your special code 
  end
end
```

But I can't find any instructions on where to put this code. In a rails app, can I just put this any crazy place I want? In a Module? A Model?

Do I need to include something in the file where I define my monkeypatch? Do I need to include my monkeypatch everywhere where I want to use it?

Comment: I'd recommend you read about [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). They're designed to help avoid the problems we see with monkey-patching.

Comment: Before you go down this road, consider making a subclass of `String` that does what you want. It's only when you need to alter the behaviour of things universally you'd want to do this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no set rule on this. Technically you can open it (the class; and add your method) anywhere. I usually make a special file called `monkey_patches.rb` and put it in `config/initializers` or in a `misc` folder in my Rails app so if theres ever a conflict I know where to look.

Also I'd advise to use a `Module` to wrap the monkey patch. Check out [3 ways to monkey patch without making a mess](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/) for more info.

His example:

```
module CoreExtensions
  module DateTime
    module BusinessDays
      def weekday?
        !sunday? && !saturday?
      end
    end
  end
end

DateTime.include CoreExtensions::DateTime::BusinessDays
```

Comment: I do try and name the files in `config/initializers` something meaningful, like in this case `business_days.rb` instead of something confusingly generic like `monkey_patches.rb` or `embarrassing_collection_of_unfortunate_hacks.rb`. If you have an editor that allows quick opening by name it's easy to pull these up if you ever have to make adjustments if their name is consistent.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the following technique described by Justin Weiss in [3 Ways to Monkey-Patch Without Making a Mess](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-ways-to-monkey-patch-without-making-a-mess/)

When in vanilla Ruby, a gem, for instance, you define a module in some file you are requiring and then [`include` (or `extend`)](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/) the module into desired class.

```
module StringMonkeypatch
  def foo
    #your special code 
  end
end

String.include StringMonkeypatch
```

When in Rails you may want to define the module in a place that gets autoloaded (look up `autoload_paths`) and in a way that follows Rails' naming convention.

For example, if monkeypatching the `Sidekiq::Testing` gem class you should mirror the file structure.

```
# in /app/<something telling>/sidekiq/testing/monkeypatch.rb
module Sidekiq::Testing::Monkeypatch
  def foo
    #your special code 
  end
end

# in /config/environment.rb, at the bootom
Sidekiq::Testing.include Sidekiq::Testing::Monkeypatch
```

Answer (score 1):

Just chiming in because it took me forever to figure this out because very little solutions worked.

• I had to use plain old require. I put it in the `config/application.rb` file. The file does not automatically load for me if you put it in the app directory like some are suggesting. I don't know why.

`patching_file_path = File.expand_path("./lib", Dir.pwd)
 Dir[patching_file_path+'/*.rb'].each {|file| require file }`

• I also put a temporary `puts "I'm Working!` in the file I'm trying to require so I can check the console to see if it's actually loading.

• Also, if you're using spring loader, before you start your console you should do `bin/spring stop` in your terminal before you start your rails console. Otherwise, it won't load new files.